# Página en blanco sin indicar error tras crear roles de usuario Administrador y Estudiante

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tras configurar roles de usuario para administrador y estudiante, la ruta siguiente me devuelve página en blanco (sin indicar error):

```
Route::any('/preguntas/{categoria}','PreguntaController@show');
```

PreguntaController.php

```
public function show($categoria)
    {
        dd($categoria);
    }
```

¿Qué puede suceder?

Otras rutas en web.php:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    $user=Auth::user();
    if (Auth::check()){
        if($user->esAdmin()){
            return view('nagusiaAdmin');
        }else{
            return view('nagusia');
        }
    }
    return view('nagusia');

});

Route::get('/admin','AdministradorController@index');
Route::get('/insertarCategoria', function () {
    return view('insertarCategoria');
});
Route::get('/insertarPregunta','CategoriaController@index');
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/admin/user/roles',['middleware'=>'role', function(){
    return "Middleware role";
}]);
Route::resource('/categorias','CategoriaController');
Route::any('/preguntas/{categoria}','PreguntaController@show');
```

Middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return redirect('/');
        //return $next($request);
    }
```

Comment: Hay mas rutas definidas en tu `route/web.php` ? puedes agregarlas?

Comment: Ya he añadido web.php Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Con `{categoria}` estas pidiendo un valor en el URL de forma obligatoria, en caso de no tener nada el `dd()` no mostrara el valor recibido.

He probado tu codigo y no me muestra ningun error al colocar el siguiente URL:

http://cursos/preguntas/holaStackOverflow

En mi caso tengo un servidor virtual configurado en WampServer usando Laravel

Ahora usando el servidor de Laravel tambien funciona.

http://127.0.0.1:8000/preguntas/hola

La salida es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Otra forma de hacer el llamado  es poniendo la ruta solamente con get

```
// usando solo ruta get
Route::get('/preguntas/{categoria}','PreguntaController@show');
```

Comment: La ruta me devolvía una página con preguntas según la categoría indicada. Tras configurar roles de usuario y el middleware se ha creado la página en blanco en vez de devolver la página. Seguiré buscando el error o partiré de la copia de seguridad anterior. Gracias.

Comment: Si has creado un middleware, revisalo para ver si tiene una regla que este filtrando la respuesta del controlador. en mi caso la prueba se hizo con un Laravel 5.8 desde cero.

Comment: Cuando creamos un Middleware, ¿a todas las rutas de web.php hay que indicarse "$user=Auth::user(); if$user->esAdmin, etc...? Hay que hacer la comprobación para cada ruta?